# "java.lang.NumberFormatException: String vazia"

Tags: java, android

My code is returning "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Empty string", but when I put number 1 and number 2 inside the onclick it works normally. Can someone help me?

public class SomaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;


 private EditText edNumber1;
   private EditText edNumber2;
   private float number2 ;
   private float number1;
   private float sum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_soma);

    edNumber1 = findViewById(R.id.editNumber1);
    edNumber2= findViewById(R.id.editNumber2);
    number1 = Float.parseFloat(edNumber1.getText().toString().trim());
    number2 = Float.parseFloat(edNumber2.getText().toString().trim());


    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCalcular);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sum = number1 + number2;

            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("soma", sum);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();

        }


    });

}
```

Comment: Hi @yasmin please post questions in Portuguese at (por favor, postar questões em português em) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question or try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: You'll need to think about what values you want `number1` and `number2` to have, in the case where the text fields are empty.  Then add some logic (probably to the `onClick` method), to check whether the text fields are empty.  But if you run `Float.parseFloat` on an empty string, you'll get that exception.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thus?
 if (number1 != null && number2!=null) {
                    try {
                        sum = number1 +number2;
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        return -1;
                    }

Comment: No.  I mean something like `if (edNumber1.getText().trim().equals("")) { number1 = 0; } else { ... do the parsing here }`

Comment: I'm trying this way inside the onclick. but as you said, the execution is being called before that, so it keeps giving problem.

Comment: if (edNumber1.getText().toString().equals("") && edNumber2.getText().toString().equals("")) {number1 = 0;  number2=0;  }

Comment: No. Wrong. "" Is an empty string and no digit and no 0. Dont calculate with it. Just stop calculation.

Comment: Specally for you there is `edNumber1.getText().toString().isEmpty()`.